# Don't resize annotation on MKMapView zoom-in/out

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Here is my code: https://ghostbin.com/paste/mvhdx

When my view is zoomed-in/out, the annotations resize. Is there a way to disable this behavior and keep the annotations at the size that they were created at?

Another bonus question, how do you prohibit a MKAnnotationView from rotating as well?

Comment: Do you mean that the annotations stay the same size on the screen but change relative to the map? That is the expected behavior.

Comment: If you want to create shapes that are fixed to geography, you may want to look at overlays instead of annotations:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW15

Comment: Yes, the annotations stay the same size but change relative to the map. I want it to stay the same size relative to when it was drawn @Fabian

Comment: The problem with MKOverlayRenderer is that I am trying to draw an animated image. This is quite difficult since it isn't a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create shapes that are fixed to geography, you may want to look at overlays instead of annotations.

[iOS7AnimatedMapOverlay](https://github.com/jhurray/iOS7AnimatedMapOverlay) shows how to add overlays to annotations.